# Zopim Chat: How can I customize the avatar icon and chat background

Tags: android, zendesk

I'm using Zopim Chat in android application. I'm facing two issues:

Firstly, is there a way to customize the default chat avatar image? 
I tried searching for a style associated with the drawable in the values.xml (as suggested in their [documentation](https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/android-chat-sdk/customization#you-cant-find-what-you-wish-to-customize)) but didn't find anything.

Second, how does one apply a different background colour? Here's what I added to my values.xml file:

```
<style name="chat_widget_background">
        <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

I expected the chat background to be red but it's still the default grey. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

1 - Chat Agent Image is settable from the Zopim Dashboard in "personal settings". The image will be automatically set on the Android App. This feature isn't available in free plan, as you can se in Pricing Table (https://www.zopim.com/pricing).

2 - If you want to apply a different background color to bubble chat go to "values"->"chat_style.xml" and edit the following

```
<style name="_chat_bubble_visitor">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/mycolor</item>
    <item name="android:background">set your background from @drawable or @color</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/chat_bubble_min_height</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">@dimen/chat_bubble_min_width</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">start|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/chat_bubble_padding</item>
</style>
```

and

```
<style name="_chat_bubble_agent">
   ....
</style>
```

If you have to set the main chat's background, set it in the activity that contains the zopim chat fragment.